# Connecting multiple android phones to RFduino via BLE connection

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, rfduino

I'm developing an android app that reads information from an RFduino. I'm using the BLEButton example in RFduino, this example sends a value when clicking in a button. It works fine for one android phone, but when I try to connect a second android phone, the RFduino is not visible anymore. My question is very simple, is possible to connect multiple android phones to RFduino?

Regards guys.

Answer (score 0):

if I'm not mistaken, this is not possible.
 You Phone acts as the "Central" Device, the RFDuino as "Peripheral" Device. A Peripheral Device can just be connected to one Central Device, a Central Device can maintain a connection to multiple peripherals. 
Usually the Peripheral stops advertising as soon as it is connected to a central Device.

This document gives a very Brief overview over Bluetooth Low Energy:

[Introduction to BLE](https://learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/introduction-to-bluetooth-low-energy.pdf)